# Without using the Polya–Vinogradov inequality, is there a way to get a bound of quadratic residues smaller than $~p~$?

Tags: number-theory

($~p~$ is a prime and the symbols below are quadratic characters.)

If we consider the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\frac{i}{p}\right)$$ 
we can use the Polya-Vinogradov to say it is of scale at most $O(\sqrt{p}\log{p})$. But I just want to show that this is of scale smaller than $~p~$, that is of scale $o(p^{1-\epsilon})$ for some small $\epsilon$. Any suggestions?

Comment: **Welcome to the site !** Add this to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!

Comment: The proof of https://proofwiki.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya-Vinogradov_Inequality is quite elementary I doubt you can do much simpler than that.

Comment: (in the case $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, the case $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ is obvious as $(-1/p) = 1$ implies your sum is $0$)

Comment: For the general case, when the sum is up to an arbitrary $n$, I agree that we must use the polya-vinogradov ineqaulity, but this is such a special case :(